# error: /tmp/SASM/macro.o: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-14.04, nasm

I have been working on SASM ide using NASM. While building, this error keeps in reoccurring

> Build started...
>  Warning! Errors have occurred in the build:
>   gcc: error: /tmp/SASM/macro.o: No such file or directory

```
%include "io.inc"

section .data
    msg db 'Hello, world!', 0

section .text
    global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp
    PRINT_STRING msg
    NEWLINE
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Comment: On my Debian Jessie system I git cloned the github repository, ran `make install` had `nasm` installed, was able to run `sasm` and your application compiled, linked, and ran without a problem. `sasm` shows a version of 3.2.0 in the help/about box.

Comment: I'd be curious what you have under `settings` menu, `build` tab and what the `linker options` line being used is.

Comment: Also might help what OS you are using as a development environment (Linux/OSX/Windows etc)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04... I tried to make install the macro but it gives me a problem in the open().

Comment: How did you install SASM (if you didn't successfully make it) - I assume you downloaded a Ubuntu-14.04 deb package?

Comment: I did indeed download an Ubuntu-14.04 deb package, is there an alternative to get it successfully working?

Comment: Building it from scratch by acquiring the latest source, install all the listed dependencies (most related to qt4) and then doing `sudo make install` (need the `sudo` on Ubuntu to elevate privileges to properly install) to build and install the program.

Comment: I have a fully upgraded 14.04 Ubuntu system here. I used `curl -L "https://build.opensuse.org/package/binary/home:Dman95/SASM?arch=x86_64&filename=sasm_3.2.0_amd64.deb&repository=xUbuntu_14.04" -o sasm320.deb` to download the deb package (64 bit) then I ran `sudo dpkg -i sasm320.deb` to install it. I installed the missing dependencies listed. The result was that I was able to run `sasm` from the command line and compile and link your code in the question with no issues.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying it, hopefully will be working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem today (with ubuntu 14.04 lts intel 64bits) but i resolved it by adding `gcc-multilib` by the ubuntu's logitec.

You can run this command for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install gcc-multilib
```

(no doubt gcc compile -and will able to do- macro.c (or/and else) to generate the missing macro.o before linking the program nasmhello ?)

Comment: Thank, installing the gcc-multilib solved my problem

Comment: E: Unable to locate package gcc-multili

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to come from missing gcc compiler. If you run sasm on x64 and build for x86, you need a cross-compiler. As mentioned above, you can install gcc-multilib. Alternatively, you can change "Mode" in Settings -> Build so that the platform you are building for is the same as the platform you are building on.

[SASM Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuf6C.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am also using SASM for NASM assembly on Ubuntu 14.04 and had the same problems after installing it using the make-file method. I deleted and reinstalled it properly using the proper package:

https://build.opensuse.org/package/binary/home:Dman95/SASM?arch=x86_64&filename=sasm_3.2.0_amd64.deb&repository=xUbuntu_14.04

1. Check if you have all the Requirements (right botton corner)
2. Download the .deb package
3. doubleclick and install

now it should be working.
(Thanks to my friend who told me what I should do.)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, verify that you are compiling for the correct architecture. Your output did not show any messages relating to architecture (i.e., "instruction does not exist in x32") so this is probably not the case. You are likely dealing with a build issue if you are able to launch the app without error and get to the point of compiling your program.

These are sample build settings for x64 architecture with nasm. Change to suit your needs:

Assembly options:

```
-g -f elf64 $SOURCE$ -l $LSTOUTPUT$ -o $PROGRAM.OBJ$
```

Linking options:

```
$PROGRAM.OBJ$ $MACRO.OBJ$ -g -o $PROGRAM$ -no-pie
```

Assembler path:

```
nasm
```

Linker path:

```
gcc
```

Object file name:

```
program.o
```